# process handle in lldbinit

Tags: linux, signals, lldb

I'd like to have the following command init my .lldbinit.

```
process handle SIGPROF -n false -p true -s false
```

The problem is that lldb won't run this command when it starts up and doesn't yet have a process.

> error: Aborting reading of commands after command #1: ' process handle
>   SIGPROF -n false -p true -s false' failed with error: No current
>   target; cannot handle signals until you have a valid target and
>   process.

How can I tell lldb to apply this command whenever it does have a process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround for this is to take the set of commands you want to run in lldb after the file you are debugging is loaded, put them in a file, and run:

```
$ lldb -s <command file> <FileToBeDebugged>
```

Then if you like this and use it often, you can make a shell alias of part up to .

If you are using Xcode, a common trick is to set a breakpoint at main in your project, put the commands you want to run there, and then make it "auto-continue".

Comment: Oh of course, I hadn't thought of the auto-continue, great idea.

Comment: didn't work for me on lldb 6.0.0: after writing `Executing commands in ...` it fails with `error: No current process; cannot handle signals until you have a valid process.` when my command is `process handle --stop false --notify false SIGUSR1 SIGUSR2`

Answer (score 2):

As of right now, I don't think you can

Allowing this would require one of two things:

- a model where LLDB records your preferences and applies them to processes as they come about (only the first one? all of them?)
- a model where LLDB has "event hooks" for things like a process has shown up, a process has gone away, and you could script the hook (via LLDB commands or Python) to perform certain actions, including setting signal handling