# Problems with hitting Line Of Code breakpoints in D code with GDB and LLDB

Tags: gdb, d, lldb

I've made sure to build my D program with the `-g` flag (add symbolic debug info) and it looks like I can set simple LOC breakpoints in both GDB and LLDB like this: `b SomeModule.d:42` - the debugger replies with a memory address for the new breakpoint.

However when I `run` the program from the debugger, it gets stopped somewhere completely different than `SomeModule.d:42`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D is a safe by default, garbage-collected by default, language.
So in addition to your own breakpoints, programs will often be interrupted by the Garbage Collector Signals (SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2).

In GDB, this can be prevented by:

```
(gdb) handle SIGUSR1 nostop noprint
Signal        Stop      Print   Pass to program Description
SIGUSR1       No        No      Yes             User defined signal 1
(gdb) handle SIGUSR2 nostop noprint
Signal        Stop      Print   Pass to program Description
SIGUSR2       No        No      Yes             User defined signal 2
```

Even better, automate by putting the above 2 commands in a file and start GDB with `-x gdb_command_file`.

The corresponding LLDB-ese sounds different:

```
(lldb) process handle --stop false --notify false SIGUSR1 SIGUSR2
```

I'm [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572233/process-handle-in-lldbinit) sure it's possible to automate it similarly with LLDB [alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431579/permanently-configuring-lldb-in-xcode-4-3-2-not-to-stop-on-signals).